# How to write parent item in Fluent UI groupedList component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am using Fluent UI. I need groupedList component, but there is something I couldn't fix. Parents are always group, but I want to aadd few items as parents just like the picture below.

I saw a github issue below, but seems it wasn't fixed. Is there any way to achive what I want?

https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/10971

[image]